# quarks annihilation process

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, subatomic

I am appreciating particle physics and I read about mesons. In quark's model, mesons are pairs of quark-antiquark. Now I think that in general matter-antimatter annihilate and so I don't understand how meson could be possible. Why don't a couple up-antiup annihilates?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The pion does indeed annihilate into photon pairs. But it is an EW process, so the lifetime is large and the pion is long lived. Actually, setting EW couplings to zero the pion would be stable since there would be no lighter hadron it could decay into.